# Performing regression using LIBSVM in Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, regression, libsvm

I am working on multivariate time series estimation. I am not quite sure if LIBSVM does that. How can I solve the basic univariate linear problem?

Suppose I have x = [1990,1991,1992,1993,1994]  and y = [1,2,3,4,5]. Now I would like to predict the value at testx = 1995 using LIBSVM in Matlab. I tried using the toolbox but the results I got is

```
model = svmtrain(y,x,'-s 3 -t 0 -c 1 -p 0.1');
*
optimization finished, #iter = 0
nu = 0.000000
obj = 0.000000, rho = -1.000000
nSV = 0, nBSV = 0
>> TST = 6;
[predicted_label, accuracy, prob_estimates]=svmpredict(TST,testx,model);
Mean squared error = 25 (regression)
Squared correlation coefficient = -1.#IND (regression)
```

What is going on here? As the data I gave is linear I have chosen -t 0 which is linear kernel.

Comment: Can you explain, how your string of options (`'-s 3 -t 0 -c 1 -p 0.1'`) relates to what the [documentation on `svmtrain`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/svmtrain.html) has to say? where do you find that `-t 0` is a linear kernel?

Comment: @Schorsch the function you refer to is from the statistics toolbox, *not* `libsvm`'s matlab interface which is, unfortunately, also called `svmtrain` by default.

Comment: @AllIsWell two things (1) you didn't show output of svmpredict (e.g. `predicted_label`) so it is hard to help based on that and (2) you didn't model your data as a time series but rather as univariate regression.

Comment: @Schorsch Hi thanks for your response. You can refer to http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/ for the authors documentation

Comment: @MarcClaesen hello Marc. Thanks for your response and the predicted_label I got for that inputs is 1 and accuracy = [0;25;NaN]

Comment: Hello @MarcClaesen could you please tell me if this works. I am holding this stuff for 4 months

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured out what's wrong. The input I am passing through is a row vector. Libsvm takes an input in a column vector format. x should be m*n where m is the number of data and n is the number of features and y is a column label vector. 
Thanks to Sriram who helped me solve the problem.